# git workflow, and merging changes from master into branches

Tags: git, merge, branch, rebase

Having struggled with SVN I was told I should check out GIT, as the branches would be ideal for the workflow I am trying to achieve. I have been muddling along and think I have the basics of GIT sorted now.

We basically have a central framework that some of our clients use, and I want to have a trunk / master and using branches as normal, for dev / trying stuff out, but I would also like to create branches for each client, so I could work on client specific changes to the code. These branches would always be a branch and never end up getting merged back into the trunk / master.

The main thing I am trying to achieve is so that I can easily merge all changes FROM the trunk / master TO the various client branches, and I am getting confused with if I need to merge, or rebase.

**So my question...** Should I always be using rebase for this, and if so why? (because I want to keep the individual commits in each branch?)

**Edit** So I create a repo, and in that repo I have say file.php with `$x = 1`

- I commit that to *master*
- I create a branch called *client1*
- In *client1* I add a new file and commit
- In *client1* I change file.php so `$x = 2`

[image: git log pre merge]

- In *master* I make a change to file.php but its a new line, and $x remains `$x = 1`
- In *client1* I merge *master* and get a conflict on `$x`

Is it because I am adding a new line to file.php adjacent to `$x` that it is causing the conflict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should merge.  Rebasing will take all of the changes on master since the branch diverged from master and *recreate* them on top of the branch.  This means that each commit on master will be duplicated for every client branch you are tracking.

Merging is semantically what you're doing.  The resulting commit graph will look much nicer, and Git will have an easier time performing merges since, after each merge, the history of master will become part of the branch's own history -- Git will only have to consider the commits on master since the last merge, instead of reconsidering *every commit on master*.

Comment: ok so I have merged my master into my branch, but I am getting a conflict on a file that opposes a commit I did to that branch since the branch was made. So example... file.php has $x = 1; in master, I commit master, then branch to client1 and switch, change file.php so $x = 2; and commit that, then switch to master, make another change in file.php, commit, switch to client1 branch, merge master into branch, and conflict on file.php regarding the $x line. it seems to be overriding revs made more recently in the branch with old revs from the master. is this normal / me being dumb?

Comment: @Horse Did you change the `$x` line in master after branching, or a line near it?  I don't see Git overriding anything, rather it's telling you that both branches touched the same region of the file, and it doesn't know which one you want in your branch.  It's up to you to decide which change belongs in the client branch.

Comment: no, the master `$x` stayed the same, I changed it in branch only, merged, then the initial pre branch master commit is conflicting with the more recent branch commit

Comment: @Horse Commits past the nearest common ancestor of the two branches (the "merge base") are not considered at all.  It is not possible for a "pre branch commit" to interfere with a merge.

Comment: @Horse You might look at the output of `git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --graph --decorate --all` and make sure that the commit graph is what you expect.

Comment: Have added some info to the OP, and a log output